# Odoo python, product priceHistory in current order only

Tags: python, odoo

I'm a odoo user without development skills.
I have a custom module with a issue. 
I explain how module work: I can add in purchase order products lines with custom price and quantity by scanning barcode in a New scanning field. If I scan more time same barcode, in same product line is increase quantity. In new scan barcode field, before scan barcode, I can type new product price and after scan barcode. Will be add line product with new price.
If I scan barcode 1 time, will add product with qty 1, and default supplier price. If I type in new scanning field new price and scan again barcode, will update product line with 1 qty increase and new price. Without priceHistory feature, if I scan again barcode (without type new price), will add 1 qty increase and new price previous updated, it will be substitute with default supplier price. With priceHistory, I can hold (fixed) new price updated, and if I will scan again barcode, new price will not be substitute.
Issue is this:
new price is applied to othes PO of others suppliers also, not only in this current PO.  I need priceHistory fix price history only in current purchase order. Each order own priceHistory data.
Currently code work, If product Shoes I apply new price 1 $ to order PO1 with supplier A, when I will create new orders (PO2,PO3,etc) with others supplier B, supplier C, D, etc.. When I will add product Shoes, priceHistory apply always 1$ (price PO1 of supplier A). This is the Issue, I need to apply 1$ only in PO1 of supplier A, and not in all order (PO2,PO3, of others suppliers)
I'm not a developer, please anyone can be help to correct code? And write me modify to do.
Thanks very much

BELOW ALL COMPLETE CODE

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import api, fields, models
from odoo.exceptions import Warning
import math
import dateutil.relativedelta
import datetime
import locale

# added the price history map
priceHistory = {}

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    """Inherit Purchase Order."""

    _inherit = "purchase.order"
    barcode = fields.Char(string='Barcode', size=50)

    def _add_product(self, product, qty, price):
        corresponding_line = self.order_line.filtered(lambda r: r.product_id.id == product.id)
        supplierinfo = product.mapped('seller_ids')[:1]
        if corresponding_line:
            corresponding_line[0].product_qty += float(qty)
            corresponding_line[0].price_unit = float(price) or supplierinfo.price
        else:
            self.order_line += self.order_line.new({
                'product_id': product.id,
                'product_qty': qty,
                'date_planned': fields.Datetime.to_string(datetime.datetime.now() - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)),
                'name': product.name,
                'product_uom': product.uom_id.id,
                'price_unit': float(price) or supplierinfo.price,       
                'taxes_id': product.supplier_taxes_id,
            })
        return True

    @api.onchange('barcode')
    def barcode_scanning(self):
        """Barcode decode."""
        if self.barcode:
            scan_barcode = self.barcode
            barcode = scan_barcode
            qty_position = scan_barcode.find('*')
            price_position = scan_barcode.find('/')

            if price_position > 0:
                price = scan_barcode[:price_position].replace(',','.')
                barcode = scan_barcode[price_position + 1:]
            else:
                price = 0

            if qty_position > 0:
                qty = scan_barcode[price_position + 1:qty_position].replace(',','.')
                barcode = scan_barcode[qty_position + 1:]
            else:
                if float(price) > 0:
                    qty = 0
                else:
                    qty = 1

            #added, to search internal reference
            product_id = self.env['product.product'].search([('default_code', '=ilike', barcode)], limit=1)
            # product_id = self.env['product.product'].search([('default_code', '=', barcode)])
            if barcode and not product_id:
                product_id = self.env['product.product'].search([('barcode', '=', barcode)])
                if barcode and not product_id:
                    self.barcode = barcode = None
                    raise Warning('Barcode sconosciuto')

              if product_id:
                # get the history price
                if price_position == -1:
                    #if priceHistory.has_key(product_id.id):
                    if product_id.id in priceHistory.keys():
                        price = priceHistory[product_id.id]
                self._add_product(product_id, qty, price)
                self.barcode = barcode = None
                #save the product price
                priceHistory[product_id.id] = price
                return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def _add_product(self, product, qty, price):
    corresponding_line = self.order_line.filtered(lambda r: r.product_id.id == product.id)
    # Get all Vendor List
    supplierinfo = product.mapped('seller_ids')
    for supp_info in supplierinfo:
        # Match with current PO Vendor with assign product Vendor
        if self.partner_id.id == supp_info.id:
            # Update the Pice
            price = supp_info.price
    if corresponding_line:
        corresponding_line[0].product_qty += float(qty)
        corresponding_line[0].price_unit = float(price)
    else:
        self.order_line += self.order_line.new({
            'product_id': product.id,
            'product_qty': qty,
            'date_planned': fields.Datetime.to_string(datetime.datetime.now() - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)),
            'name': product.name,
            'product_uom': product.uom_id.id,
            'price_unit': float(price),
            'taxes_id': product.supplier_taxes_id,
        })
    return True
```

Comment: Hi Dipen, I've update code, but I can not install module. I have odoo error:  500 Internal Server Error.         In odoo log there is:
           File "c:\program files\odoo moduli personalizzati\traditional_barcode\models\purchase_order.py",  
          line 17       
          def _add_product(self, product, qty, price):    
                                                    ^      
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation - - -
                Can you check code please?Thanks very much

Comment: Yes due to the indentation is not properly set on written code. I think to check your barcode function where you have the wrong indentation.

Comment: Hi Dipen, I've solved module installation, it work. But now price unit appied is always 0. If I comment priceHistory, your new code not solve my issue, if I not comment priceHistory, my issue with priceHistory is not solved, new price is applied to all orders and suppliers.

Comment: Hello Dani, New code is like this, if your PO Vendor and product vendor is matched then you have the price taken from this otherwise you have the price based on your condition.